# Categorizing the data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, categorical-data, chi-squared

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wppxK.png)I am trying to run a chi square test on a dataset and for that I need to use `pd.cut()` to formulate categories in the data set. However, I am getting this error

> ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types
>   dtype('

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import math

data_main = pd.read_csv("sample_survey.csv")
data = data_main.iloc[:, [1,2]]

data["wrkstat"] = data["wrkstat"].astype(str)
data["marital"] = data["marital"].astype(str)
cols = ['wrkstat', 'marital']

cut_points = ['Divorced', 'Married', 'Never Married', 'Seperated','Widowed']
label_names = ['Divorced1', 'Married', 'Never Married', 
'Seperated','Widowed']
data["Marital_Categories"] = pd.cut(data["marital"], cut_points)

marital_by_wrkstat = data[['wrkstat', 'marital_categories']]
marital_by_wrkstat.head()
```

Comment: pd.cut uses continuous variables. In this case, your marital column are string types. You might want to consider using `.astype('categorical')` or explore more here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html

Comment: could you please add a sample from your data?

Comment: BernadL I tried but it says 'categorical' data type not understood

Comment: nimrodz sample added

Comment: Try it df[columnname] = pd.Categorical(df[columnname])

Comment: what is your expected output for data["Marital_Categories"]?

Comment: @nimrodz and @BernardL, to convert to categorical data type, you need `.astype('category')`, not `.astype('categorical')`.

Comment: https://codingdisciple.com/chi-squared-python.html             Nimrodz I want to categorize the data and have count as shown in the link

Comment: M.r_L still doesn't work

Comment: @Aditya Shah what is the difference between data["marital"] and data["Marital_Categories"]? you want that the categories would be `int` group number?

Comment: My goal is to get a distribution in such a way that I can have separate counts of each category based on their status in the wrkstat column. The idea is to perform the chi square test as mentioned in the link